# This [calc] does not compute

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/calc/info) of the [calc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/calc) tag states:

> calc refers to anything remotely related to anything about calculating
>   anything. Because of its vague purpose, it should be avoided.

I'm curious what is the value of tag, which is by definition of itself is discouraged from being used?

On moment of writing this question there were [309](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/calc) questions tagged with this tag.

Comment: It all adds up to burniation.... :)

Comment: Can we see some calculations on [calc] burniation, please?

Comment: Title suggestion. "This tag needs burnination, says my [calc]ulation". And yes, I did spend some time, to make that title rhyme :-)

Comment: Suggested title: [calc] does not compute

Comment: In all seriousness, you should add the [burninate-request] tag here. Calls for the tag's removal

Comment: @Machavity added `burnintate-request`. As for the title, sadly SO doesn't allow me to start a title with a tag in a prefix :(

Comment: @igormilla Add `This` in front. Should work

Comment: @Machavity Just me or is [calc]ulation better? Nitpicking. :)

Comment: I know [how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46228192/8041231) in calc.exe on Windows (and SQL language), shall I answer?

Comment: My [calc]ulations show that this tag needs to be burned.

Comment: @Victoria OP seems to abandon that question, but you can give it a try if you want

Comment: what should be done with questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25835591/how-to-calculate-percentage-between-the-range-of-two-values-a-third-value-is)?

Comment: @eis someone retagged it with `[algorithm]`, and I like this solution. Calculation is something you do once, and algorithm is something generic and reusable, I think it nicely aligns with general goal of StackOverflow.

Comment: ok, went ahead and removed `[calc]` from that one